# Chrome does not execute project in netbeans just display script

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to run script in chrome but it shows code in chrome when I execute it but when I execute in webkit it works and this is what displays in chrome

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 462
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!--
  To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
  To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
   and open the template in the editor.
  -->
    <html>
     <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning my computers of malwares this problem stopped occuring. Before that I tried almost everything but nothing helped for good. Sometimes this problem occured and sometimes not. So I guess such not nondeterministic behavior could be caused by malware.